# Как убрать ожидание выполнения функции?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, возникли 2 проблемки.
У меня есть `Activity`, в которой заполняется различная информация. В этом же `Activity` идет поиск местоположения человека.

- Первая проблема. Так как в `Activity` идет определение местоположения (определяется через интернет), поэтому при запуске `Activity` идет задержка времени (идет поиск местоположения),  получается, что приходится ждать какое то время перед тем как откроется `Activity`. Нужно чтобы пока человек заполняет другую информацию, выполнялось определение местоположения. Как это осуществить?
- Вторая проблема. Через интернет не всегда правильно определяет местоположение. Зачастую правильно показывает только страну и город,а улицу и дом заменяет на `null`. Причем идет постоянное обновление данных и они вместо того, чтобы перезаписать прошлые в `editText` добавляются за прошлыми. Мне нужно попробовать сделать так, чтобы был полный адрес без `null`, даже если он будет немного неточным, т.е. как полностью определится, так сразу записывался в `myLocationText`.
- Элемент списка

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
LocationManager locationManager;
String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
updateWithNewLocation(location);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);
}

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {//постоянное обновление.
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    updateWithNewLocation(null);
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){ }
};

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
String latLongString;
TextView myLocationText;
myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);

String addressString = "No address found";

if (location != null) {                              
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            if (address.getCountryName() != null) {
                country_location = address.getCountryName(); 
            }
            if (address.getLocality() != null) {
                city_location = address.getLocality(); 
            } 
            if (address.getThoroughfare() != null) {
                street_location = address.getThoroughfare(); 
            }
            if (address.getFeatureName() != null) {
                house_location = address.getFeatureName(); 
            }

            geolocation.append(country_location).append(",");
            geolocation.append(city_location).append(",");
            geolocation.append(street_location).append(",");
            geolocation.append(house_location).append(".");

        }
            addressString = geolocation.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
} else {
    latLongString = "No location found";
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
}
myLocationText.setText(addressString);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По первой задаче - помогут либо самописное на тредах, либо готовое решение - [AsyncTask](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%5Basynctask%5D&target_type=posts).

По второму вопросу. Присмотритесь в эту часть кода

```
geolocation.append(country_location).append(",");
geolocation.append(city_location).append(",");
geolocation.append(street_location).append(",");
geolocation.append(house_location).append(".");
```

Здесь происходит добавление без проверки на содержимое. Может объединить это с условиями выше? плюс geolocation не очищается.

Comment: Объединил, теперь она просто будет записывать адрес без части, которая в null. Т.е., например, город в null и его в editText уже не будет. Как можно сделать проверку на присутствие всех частей адреса ( страны, города, улицы, номера дома), если какая то в null, то сделать обновление - updateWithNewLocation(location); и дописать к другим частям

Comment: А зачем дописывать, если можно собрать строку заново. В данном случае это проще и быстрее.

Comment: Что то наподобие ( напримере номера дома):

  if (address.getFeatureName() != null) {
               house_location = address.getFeatureName(); 
               geolocation.append(house_location).append(".");
} else {
updateWithNewLocation(location);
house_location = address.getFeatureName();
 geolocation.append(house_location).append(".");
} ?

Только проблема будет в том, что если повторно getFeatureName(); выдаст null, как тогда ?

Comment: если при повторном запросе выдаст `null`, то может просто пользователь сместился и текущие координаты теперь не определяются? Показывать предыдущие - нет смысла, оно уже может быть неактуальным.

Как вариант, можно просто запоминать последние 3-4 результата. Правда все зависит от цели.

Comment: Кстати хорошая мысль, несколько результатов сделать и выбрать один из них. спасибо завтра попробую и отпишусь)Эти местаположения нужны, чтобы потом на карте их отобразить.